# php break statement for different title for every page

Tags: php, break

I'm not so familiar with php. **Apologies if posted already.**
I'm using following code for set title of every page.
Config.php have ->

```
    $pag = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
     switch ($pag){
    case '/artist.php':
    $title= $db->query('select name from artist');
    $description = $db->query('select des from artist');
    break;

    case '/album.php':
    $title= $db-query('select name from album');
    $description = $db->query('select des from album');
     break;
    }
```

artist.php have ->

```
     print_r($title);
     print_r($description);
```

Everything is working fine. I want to know that when someone land on `artist.php` all four query executed or just `case /artist.php`'s two queries?

Comment: Why do you think all 4 querys should be executed? Think u know the answer by yourself, but since you've not so familiar with PHP you're may not so sure. But its not difficult... Read your code and ask yourself whats going on..

Comment: I have about 15 pages and every page have two or three queries. If all executes this results in decrease the performance.

Comment: It won't execute the code, since you're skipping it with your switch-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [Twinfriends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271736/php-break-statement-for-different-title-for-every-page/43272292#comment73612169_43271736) is correct. Because of the `break`, the program will execute just one branch of the `switch`.

You can find it yourself. One way is some debugger, which can go step-by-step. Another way is just test print (`echo()` or `var_dump()`) in each branch of the `switch`. You will see, what gets printed, and what not.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that if I get name from `artist` table that's mean the first Case's both queries executed and if I get name from `album` table that's mean second case 's  both queries executed.

Comment: @Pradeep Yes, that's true. You can read more about switch at [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)